# The proper way to add markers to a layer group in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I always add markers to a Leaflet layer group like this:

```
someMarker.addTo(someLayerGroup);
```

But looking at the docs I just realized that you can also do:

```
someLayerGroup.addLayer(someMarker);
```

Are there benefits of using one way over the other?

Answer (score 2):

When I learned Leaflet I was told that although both ways can work, it generally makes more sense to set it up the first way you described so that everything that is inherited from Layer can be brought in smoothly. This also works best when there are several markers, layers, and or layer groups in the same map.

However, this really comes into play when using Control Layer Groups. If you aren't familiar with Control Layers I recommend playing around with them and reading up on the documentation so you can see how the ordering works. Good luck.

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.2.html#control